# do i need to restart biztalk application or just host instance when changing resource?

Tags: biztalk, restart

i'm a newbie in biztalk.

i have data service access dll which are linked to the wcf.

i've just added a new column so i've updated my wcf.

so the next thing would be to update the dll which are already in the GAC.

just wondering if there's any msdn documentation about this?

or what's the best practice here?

and what exactly goes on when you restart host instance vs restarting the application?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stopping/starting a BizTalk application simply stops and restarts the associated Receive and Send ports, and prevents the Orchestrations from acting on any pending subscription items.  If you go one step further and un-enlist the Orchestration/Send Port, this removes the relevant subscription from the BizTalk Message Box database.

By compiling and deploying a new definition of your WCF datatype, you have changed the assembly within the GAC (all schemas are compiled and represented as .Net datatypes under the hood).  To have this change reflected inside the running Host Instance, you would effectively need to alter the existing DLL that is in the .Net AppDomain.  The .Net runtime does not support the removal of assembly types from an AppDomain, so you need to stop, and restart the Host Instance to effect this.

Short answer: Restart your Host Instance for any changes in data definition.

Comment: sweet, love the fact u provide a short answer too :)